# Completing NSURLRequest upon app launch

Tags: ios, multithreading, queue, nsurlrequest

So I have a tabbed iOS app, and two of the view controllers in the app each have webViews in them. Nothing else. When these views are opened, they then call the NSURLRequest I have coded in the viewDidLoad method (as we all know). Very typical, basic, simple code.

What I am trying to do but haven't been able to figure out, is how to have these requests called and completed upon app launch, as opposed to being triggered when the view controller is viewed for the first time. It just takes too long to load.

I'm not very experienced with threads and blocks so any advice would help! I do know that all the UI stuff needs to be called on the main thread/queue. I have made an attempt at using another thread (commented out in view controller 2), so any further explanation as to what I already have would be great as well.

VC 1

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://soundcloud.com/vanguardsf"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_music loadRequest:request];
}
```

VC 2

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
    _webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:screen];
    _webView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];

    NSString *netGym = @"http://www.netgym.com/login.asp";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:netGym];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    NSLog(@"%@", request );


//    if (!requestQueue) {
//        requestQueue = dispatch_queue_create("come.requestNetgym.load", NULL);
//    }

//    dispatch_queue_t requestQueue = dispatch_queue_create("come.requestNetgym.load", NULL);

//    dispatch_async(requestQueue, ^{
//        NSString *netGym = @"http://www.netgym.com/login.asp";
//        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:netGym];
//        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//        [_webView loadRequest:request];
//        NSLog(@"%@", request );
//    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use GDC to send asynchrounus NSURLRequests - they are asynchronous if You don't use them synchronously on purpose.

You can start the requests in this method:
[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3awillFinishLaunchingWithOptions): 
This is first place in application when You can execute a code just after launching is finished. You will save some time (little I suppose - this looks like a simple app).

I think that better solution is to cache the downloaded website data. In this case You will download the data first time You enter the app and the second time You will display downloaded content. In the background You will check if website has changed. If so You update the content.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you provide a code snippet?